# Move Excel Sheet Using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, excel, move

I have an excel sheet with one sheet named **`"sheet1"`** and I have added new sheet named
**`"secondsheet"`** as shown below:

```
ExcelApp.Worksheets.Add().Name = "secondSheet"
```

Now how do I move the second sheet to last as it is adding front to the "sheet1"

This is what I have done but unable to move the second sheet

```
ExcelApp.Worksheets("secondsheet").Move(After:=xlWorkBook.Worksheets(xlWorkBook.Worksheets.Count))
```

Comment: You have capitalised one of the secondsheets, perhaps that's causing problems?

Comment: @bamie9l-Sorry its a typo problem...

Comment: Try this: `ExcelApp.activeworkbook.Sheets.Add(after:=ExcelApp.activeworkbook.Sheets(ExcelApp.activeworkbook.Sheets.Count)).Name="secondSheet"`

Comment: @Tim-No...its the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it solved...There is nothing mistake with the above code but declaring of workbook made me to pull out my hair.

This is what I have done:

```
Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
xlWorkBook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Add
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax to get what you want (in VBA) is:

```
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets("sheet1")
ActiveSheet.Name = "secondSheet"
```

I always have better luck creating the sheet in the right position first, then renaming it.